# React-Native, Use specific style param for different views

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles

I'm creating custom button and use `TouchableOpacity` with a `Text` inside it. I want to use specific style items for `TouchableOpacity` and `Text` separately (e.g `padding`, `backgroundColor` for `TouchableOpacity` and `color`, `FontSize` for `Text`). The challenge is that I have my own

My code should be something like this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding:10,
    backgroundColor:'red',
  },
 text:{
    color:'white'
  }
}

<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.container, {background: this.props.style.backgroundColor, padding: this.props.style.padding}]}>
     <Text style={[styles.text, {color:this.props.style.color}]}>{label}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

It has error and says could not found `this.props.style.backgroundColor` (I test both with and without style (and of curse if it should work, it should work in both forms)). Also I want to send those styles as props.

**Edit**

I pass style as `props` to my button like this:

```
  `<CustomButton style={backgroundColor:'red', padding: 3 , textColor:'blue'} label={'Click Me'}/>`
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `background: styles.backgroundColor`?

Comment: @Stretch0, I'm not sure, because I'm passing the style as props.

Answer (score 1):

You should create another .js like colors.js and add the colors there (or more) like this :

```
export const valid = 'green';
export const background = 'red';
```

then you import them in your view with

`import * as Colors from './colors';`

And use it `Colors.background` or `Colors.valid` etc

Comment: It might be dynamic, I can't use static properties.